# Почему имена встроенных функций в Go набраны строчными буквами?

Tags: golang, дизайн-языка

Функции и переменные с именами начинающимися со сточной буквы не видны снаружи пакета, так почему встроенные типы и функции начинаются со строчной буквы? Они описаны в пакете `main`?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: Это встроенные функции. На них эта тема не распространяется. Их ведь можно использовать не только в пакете main, но и в любом другом. Это то, что нужно просто принимать как есть.

Comment: Так ведь и никакой пакадж импортировать тоже не нужно. Если заглянуть в исходник https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go , то там прямо написано, что этот файл только для документации и реально ничего не делает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имена встроенных функций не входят ни в один пакет, и в Go нет перегрузки функций, по этому если существует встроенная функция `foo`, то ни в одном пакете нельзя объявить функцию с именем `foo`.

Если бы встроенные функции начинались с большой буквы, например `Append` или `Close`, то нельзя было бы сделать метод с таким именем, что весьма неудобно.

Более того, если в будущем появится новая встроенная функция, например `Move`, то надо будет переписывать все пакеты, имеющие такую функцию. Более того, т.к. это публичное API, надо будет переписать все пакеты, в которых эта функция вызывается.

По этому встроенные функции начинаются с маленькой буквы. Это не мешает использованию этих функций в публичном API, и при добавлении новых встроенных функций будет сломано меньше кода.